# Optimize NOT IN query in Access SQL

Tags: ms-access

I need to optimize the SQL Query

```
select * from tblProdutcs 
where ProductCode Not in 
(SELECT ProductCode From tblPrice 
WHERE DateExtracted=#15-Sep-2013# 
order by ProductCode) 
order by ProductCode
```

This is taking far too long (about 45-60 seconds currently.

Comment: Do you need every field in tblProducts?  You can lower some overhead by only pulling back the fields you actually need.

Comment: tblProducts which having only 2 columns (ProductCode and ProductName) and are needed. All other information has been stripped out from the table into a separate table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove order by ProductCode in the inner query because the outher
  query does ordering as well
- Be sure that both of your tables have index insert an id field which
  is primary key, unique and autoincerement (if neccessary) to both
  tables
- Also try this query. it may increase speed as well, but I don't know
  why. It should be asked if there is a better performance effect
  between these two ways

  SELECT pro.* FROM tblProducts pro    LEFT JOIN tblPrice pri    ON pro.ProductCode = pri.ProductCode    WHERE pri.ProductCode IS NULL AND    pri.DateExtracted=#15-Sep-2013#     ORDER BY pro.ProductCode

Comment: What column should index be created on? The ProductCode or DateExtracted and in which table(s)?

Comment: both table should have index. Generaly id fields are used for indexing tables.

Comment: This has helped bring down time to about 10-15 seconds but can we still optimize it to get records faster?

Comment: which one ordering or creating index

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblProducts pro
LEFT JOIN tblPrice pri
ON pro.ProductCode = pri.ProductCode
WHERE pri.ProductCode IS NULL AND
pri.DateExtracted=#15-Sep-2013# 
ORDER BY pro.ProductCode

returns all records that are in both tables. Whereas I need records from tblProducts which are not in tblPrice for today's date.

Comment: SELECT pro.* use this

Comment: You need to index `tblProducts.DateExtracted` for better performance.